# How do I change the difficulty level?

Tags: sleeping-dogs

I was just going through my old games and tried a bit of sleeping dogs.

However, the game was so hard that I raged millions on times. I couldn't find any difficulty slider in the options.

Can I change my difficulty or am I stuck at ragemode?

Comment: What was it about the game that made it hard? Is there a specific mission you are struggling on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, but you are kinda stuck on ragemode. There is no difficulty setting.

The game is stuck on 1 difficulty.

Comment: Damn, guess I have to go to another game then.

Comment: There are some DLCs which make the game easier, see [this question on how to _disable_ them](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/116223/88), it lists said DLCs