# Sleeping Dogs GOTY: How do I prevent getting the DLC bonuses in the beginning?

Tags: sleeping-dogs

In Sleeping Dogs GOTY, I get all the DLCs unlocked after an hour of play, and then I get like 8 level-ups, 200000$ (and also cars, outfits etc...). So, I learned almost every skill there is in the beginning. It killed for me all the motivation in playing it.

**Is that normal? How was it in the original Sleeping Dogs?

Is there a way to prevent getting the DLC bonuses in the beginning?**

Comment: I remember they were selling money and experience as DLC (one of the few reasons I will never buy this otherwise excellent game), I'm guess they made that part of the GOTY edition.

Comment: Yes, and I haven't found the way to turn it off, before the beginning... I had to sit through like at least 30 *something unlocked* messages in the beginning.

Comment: @JustGoscha I edited your question to avoid it from getting close votes as 'not constructive' and as per: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/why-did-they-design-it-that-way-anyway-and-why-do-we-allow-or-disallow-thes

Comment: Yeah, I got screwed over less. I bought the base game and played it till the end (great game). Then during the steam sales I bought all the dlc's cheap and noted afterwads the increase in xp and such. Kinda lame :p

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume GOTY includes all DLC listed in Steam under the [DLC pack](http://store.steampowered.com/sub/26227/). The only way I know about to actually "deactivate" a DLC is asking Steam support to *permanently* remove it from your account without any refunds. So I can only give you a list of the benefits provided by the DLCs here and you have to be honest with yourself to not "use" them, e.g. always consider yourself to be 200k poorer than you are:

- I'll skip the cars, clothes and weapons, since they shouldn't be difficult to notice - basically you don't own anything but a motorbike and your own clothes in the beginning
- [Police Protection Pack](http://store.steampowered.com/app/215249): Apart from the SWAT stuff it adds the "High Speed" mission and gives you some police XP (not enough for a full point on its own though)
- [The High Roller Pack](http://store.steampowered.com/app/215244): $200k and premature access to the Tuono vehicle and High Roller outfit
- [Martial Arts Pack](http://store.steampowered.com/app/202191/) gives you slight Triad XP boost (again not enough for a point on its own, but still...)
- [The Red Envelope Pack](http://store.steampowered.com/app/215243): those red envelopes scattered around town containing $50k each
- [Top Dog Gold Pack](http://store.steampowered.com/app/215242) / [Top Dog Silver Pack](http://store.steampowered.com/app/215241): A total of both 8 police and triad skill points
- [The Zodiac Tournament](http://store.steampowered.com/app/215258): That tournament

So in summary, if you don't want to use the too severe DLC bonuses, don't collect the red envelopes and always leave $200k and 8 triad/police skill point unused...

---

If you're on PC (or can somehow access the respective files on your console), you can remove/rename the respective files (and probably have to deactivate updates for the game) I found a list of the DLCs' respective filenames [here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/202170/discussions/0/846945955286761354/), extended by me on how cheat-y they are:

> 1E6323E1.dat Top Dog Gold Pack           # pure cheat
>   576E446C.dat Top Dog Silver Pack         # pure cheat
>   AC8D6F78.dat High Roller Pack            # pure cheat
>   E58008F5.dat Red Envelope Pack           # cheat, but you have to search them
>   E80C9CFE.dat police protection pack      # swat clothes/vehicles, high speed mission (farm police XP)
>   3E97A062.dat Tactical Soldier Pack       # clothes & weapons
>   8C79ECFB.dat Retro Triad Pack            # clothes
>   67EE992C.dat Martial Arts Pack           # clothes, dummy, shaolin showdown mission (farm triad XP)
>   81F578F0.dat Dragon Master Pack          # collection of other DLC
>   613E5E9C.dat Square Enix Character Pack  # clothes
>   849D8C70.dat Street Racer Pack           # additional races
>   B41D5130.dat Community Gift Pack         # ???
>   BA29F60B.dat Ghost Pig Pack              # clothes
>   CD90EBFD.dat Screen Legends Pack         # clothes, sword
>   D500D5B5.dat Deep Undercover Pack        # clothes, car, CB radio
>   F3249186.dat Gangland Style Pack         # tattoos
>   FD1036BD.dat Valve T-Shirt Pack          # clothes
>   779AC7EF.dat SWAT Pack                   # cop mission (clothes?)
>   5AE2D067.dat Drunken Fist Pack           # clothes
>   9ADD7588.dat Monkey King Pack            # clothes, cloud-bike
>   41CADD1F.dat Law Enforcer Pack           # HKPD clothes & cars
>   28333911.dat Movie Masters Pack          # clothes
>   C8F81F7D.dat Triad Enforcer Pack         # clothes, car
>   7A1653E4.dat gsp pack                    # clothes
>
> Story DLC:
>   D3D01205.dat Wheels of Fury              # mission for/with powerful car
>   E0E8FC75.dat Zodiac Tournament Pack
>   13EFB7EA.dat Nightmare in North Point    # separate from main game
>   ????????.dat Year of the Snake           # separate from main game

Comment: Yes you could do this but why do I need to restrict myself... for developers too lazy to put in a switch in the GOTYE edition to deactivate the DLCs with the skill bonuses and money in the beginning... (apart from that it's just plain stupid to bring out these kinds of DLCs)

Comment: Tell me more... Anyway, these are the only two solutions I know of - are you on PC or a console?

Comment: You can deactivate DLC by right clicking on the game in your Steam games list, going to the "DLC" tab, and unchecking the DLC you don't want to have installed.

Comment: @Smudge So the feature mentioned in [the other answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/166947/88) got finally released? Thanks for the info, I haven't used Steam that extensively recently

Answer (score 8):

With the introduction of a proper system in the current Steam Beta, which will go live soon, you can actually disable single DLC's based on your preference:

[image: Screenshot of DLC properties]

Just remove the tick for the DLC's you don't like and those won't be installed when you install the game. If the game is already installed, it deletes this content off your hard disk and you have to redownload the DLC content if you want to play this content again, which can lead to a hefty download if the DLC Data is more than just a license file (e.g. Levels and Textures etc).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty bat file you can run to quickly eliminate cheaty DLC's
just copy all below to notepad and save as disabledlc.bat (or whatever you want to name it) in your SleepingDogs folder  and then run it.
Check Zommuters post above for which DLC's are disabled and add your own if needed.
Make sure these commands are placed below each other as shown below.

```
del 1E6323E1.dat
del 576E446C.dat
del AC8D6F78.dat 
del E58008F5.dat
del E80C9CFE.dat 
del 3E97A062.dat 
del 67EE992C.dat 
del 41CADD1F.dat
```