# What's the fastest way to make money in Sleeping Dogs?

Tags: sleeping-dogs

I'm trying to make bank in *Sleeping Dogs*. I've been doing the cockfights, which are sort of random. Is there an established method of making money that has a really good return on investment?

Comment: Buy the DLC with the envelopes. Search them. Profit. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/116223/sleeping-dogs-goty-how-do-i-prevent-getting-the-dlc-bonuses-in-the-beginning?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind cheesing, just get to a save point close to some high stakes cockfight location, bet the max, save if you win, reload if you lose.

Takes a while, but gets the job done, I suppose. Also nets you that one achievement.